# Cant start more than 10 nodejs processes

Tags: node.js

Recently, I have changed to another server for my application. The new server has the same specifications as the old one. HAProxy is put in front of those processes for load balacing

The problem is that whenever I start more than 10 node processes, the other processes start to stop accepting connection (HAProxy tells me that). If I keep the number of processes at 10, everything works normally

I am using nodejs 0.8.25.

Cluster module is not an option as I am using faye, and previously the cluster module caused a lot of memory leak.

I am not sure what are the possible reasons for this kind of error

not sure if it is related, `/var/log/syslog` is full of this `Oct  3 12:39:11 myapp kernel: [64449.515963] nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `ufw` have changed the sysclt settings to limit the number of connection to 65536. After disabling `utw` and set the limit to a much higher number, everything is good now.

More info can be found here http://pc-freak.net/blog/resolving-nf_conntrack-table-full-dropping-packet-flood-message-in-dmesg-linux-kernel-log/